# ‘Apt’ in this context

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

Google Translate gives this definition:

> “apt - having a tendency to do something”

If I want to show my disagreement, is it suitable to say so:

> “I’m not ***apt to think*** so.”

Is it weird?

Comment: "Apt" describes a tendency, likelihood, so it is not usually used to describe a single, isolated act. "Soundable" is not a word.

Comment: “I’m not **inclined** to think so.”